# Transform.scale and canvas.scale not Scaling at the Same Rate

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app where I'm rendering a `CustomPainter` and a Widget in a `Stack`. When I pass the scale and translate amount into [`canvas.scale()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/scale.html) and [`canvas.translate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/translate.html), then pass the scale into the [`Transform.scale`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.scale.html) and [`Transform.translate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.translate.html) - the two items scale offset's scale differently. View at the bottom of this post to see what this looks like.

Here is the code that has the `Stack` widget:

```dart
Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      CustomPaint(
                        painter: CanvasPainter(
                          scale: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).scale,
                          focalPoint: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).focalPoint,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Transform.scale(
                        scale: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).scale,
                        child: Transform.translate(
                          offset: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).focalPoint + Offset(150, 150),
                          
                            child: Text(
                              'Hello world',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                            ),
                        
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
```

Then the CanvasPainter Logic:

```dart
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    ...
    canvas.scale(scale);
    canvas.translate(focalPoint.dx, focalPoint.dy);

    ...// render the lines
  }
```

However, when I run the code the Hello World text widget and the line rendered by the CustomPainter don't scale the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to specify the [`alignment`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/alignment.html) property in `Transform.scale`. Alignment is set by default `Alignment.center`. However, the [`canvas.scale`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/scale.html) method works by multiplying the space between the points by the scale you pass which in which is equivalent to `Alignment.topLeft` using a Transform Widget. The final code is:

```dart
Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      CustomPaint(
                        painter: CanvasPainter(
                          scale: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).scale,
                          focalPoint: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).focalPoint,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Transform.scale(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft, // <- new line
                        scale: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).scale,
                        child: Transform.translate(
                          offset: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).focalPoint + Offset(150, 150),
                          
                            child: Text(
                              'Hello world',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                            ),
                        
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following code work?

```dart
Transform.scale(
  scale: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).scale,
  child: Transform.translate(
    offset: ref.watch(frameStateProvider).focalPoint + Offset(150, 150),
    child: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        CustomPaint(
          painter: CanvasPainter(),
        ),
        Text(
          'Hello world',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

And remove `focalPoint` and `scale` from CanvasPainter.

Comment: This is what I would like to do, but I need to understand the difference between `Transform.scale` and the Scale method inside of the canvas. Because I need to calculate the point on the canvas based on where I touch the screen

Comment: In my final solution I adopted this as a way to clean up my code. See my new answer on the relation between Transform.scale and the canvas.scale